# c++: std::advance (once) goes to end of list

Tags: c++, listiterator, stdadvance

I've never walked into the following problem with iterators, so I really do not know where the solution might start. I have a LIST "StringOfPearls" which is permuted right before I do the following:

```
DNAr = StringOfPearls->begin(); // Added 1 element to the beginning of this list in earlier line of code
cout << "pos DNAr before bumping by 1: " << distance(DNAreplicase, StringOfPearls->begin()) << endl;
advance(DNAreplicase, 1);
cout << "pos DNAr after bumping by 1: " << distance(DNAreplicase, StringOfPearls->begin()) << endl;
```

Returns:

```
pos DNAr before bumping by 1: 0
pos DNAr after bumping by 1: 10
```

No doubt I'm just missing something silly, but can anyone help me out?

Comment: please show a [mcve]. From the code it isnt even clear if `DNAreplicase` is an iterator for `StringOfPearls`.

Comment: Where is `DNAreplicase` initialised?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) correctly. `begin` iterator is the first argument, e.g.

```
distance(StringOfPearls->begin(), DNAreplicase)
```

This is the convention for all functions taking pairs of iterators denoting a range.

Comment: Update for C++11: _"The value may be negative if random-access iterators are used and first is reachable from last."_ source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance